# c# Load list from Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have sharepoint and I want to read items from specific list. I can load 53 lists from server but I cannot find what specific list I have to read.
Address of my sharepoint is:

`http://sp2.intranet.mmmm.net/LWW/Europe/Warsaw/loc/eng/Lists/CollaborationIntracompany/all.aspx`

And on this page I can see four tasks:

[image: Tasks in sharepoint]

My code to read lists from sharepoint looks like below:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext("http://sp2.intranet.mmmmm.net/"))
            {
                //   var site = ctx.Site;
                //...
                Web web = ctx.Web;

                // Retrieve all lists from the server. 
                ctx.Load(web.Lists,
                             lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title, // For each list, retrieve Title and Id. 
                                                    list => list.Id,
                                                    list => list.DefaultDisplayFormUrl,
                                                    list => list.ItemCount));

                // Execute query.
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                var listsNames = new List<string>();
                foreach (List list in web.Lists)
                {
                    listsNames.Add(list.Title);
                }
```

And as I mentioned I can read 53 lists, and I see list with name Tasks, but itemCount in this list is 0. What that is mean? Another lists have any items (not all).
All lists that I get from server:

```
_SysImages,Announcements,Company News,Contacts,Content and Structure Reports,Documents,Events,Form Templates,fpdatasources,Homepage,Images,Links,List Template Gallery,Master Page Gallery,Pages,Quick Deploy Items,Reporting Metadata,Reporting Templates,Reusable Content,Site Assets,Site Collection Documents,Site Collection Images,Site Pages,Site Template Gallery,Solution Gallery,Suggested Content Browser Locations,Tasks,TaxonomyHiddenList,Team Discussion,Test Document,Test Document SP2010 WF Tasks,Theme Gallery,This Week in Pictures Library,Web Part Gallery,wfpub,Workflow History,Workflow Tasks,Workflows
```

Maybe I should read CollaborationIntracompany list, but I don't see that list in result from sharepoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read from the specific subsite.   Most likely the url is

http://sp2.intranet.mmmm.net/LWW/Europe/Warsaw/

Then you'll see your list in the lists object.

Sp site lists property doesn't recursively go through all lists in all subsites underneath.   It only picks ones in that site.

Comment: Ok,I've added subset and now I retreive list that looks like that: Documents,fpdatasources,Images,Master Page Gallery,Office Discussion board,Pages,Useful links,WAW Gallery,WAW Office Announcements,WAW Office visitors Calendar,WAW ORG CHARTS,Workflow Tasks and I still cannot see Tasks list

Comment: hover over the URL of one of the tasks to open...what's its URL for the document?

Comment: This is the link http://sp2.intranet.mmmm.net/LWW/Europe/Warsaw/loc/eng/Lists/CollaborationIntracompany/DispForm.aspx?ID=221&ContentTypeId=0x0100878775

Comment: try this as the subsite "http://sp2.intranet.mmmm.net/LWW/Europe/Warsaw/loc/eng" with the http:// in front of it

Comment: Now it works, but I have a problem to retreive these to task items, but I'll write about it in another question, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988642/c-sharp-sharepoint-cannot-retreive-items-from-list-programmatically