# C# Sharepoint cannot retreive items from list programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have list in sharepoint. I can retreive this list but I cannot retreive items from this list:
[image]

My code looks lite this:

```
 using (var ctx = new ClientContext("http://sp2.intranet.mmmm.net/LWW/Europe/Warsaw/loc/eng/"))
            {

                Web web = ctx.Web;

                var tasksList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("IC-Portal-Announcements");

                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";

                ListItemCollection collListItem = tasksList.GetItems(camlQuery);

                ctx.Load(collListItem, items => items.Include(
                    item => item.Id,
                    item => item.DisplayName,
                    item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
                    ));

                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
                {

                }
```

In oListItem I still see "IC-Portal-Announcements" in displayName, but I don't know how to get two tasks that are seen on the picture.

Comment: you have a row limit on your task...so you'll get 100 random items...see this on filtering your data - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171798/caml-query-for-filtering-list-view

Comment: Ok, I see, but how to take all tasks from this specific list? In the example are queries how to take for specific status and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for starters you can try these queries:

```
var q1  = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
var viewfields = new string[] {"Id", "DisplayName", "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"};
var q2  = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(1000, viewfields);
```

For the second one you can probably leave out your include statement on load
I'm not sure if the names of the viewfields are correct. You could check with u2u caml query builder

For more specific information on caml search try [this blog](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/caml-and-the-client-object-model/)

Comment: camlQuery.ViewXml =
    "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Task_x0020_Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>!Heads-up</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";

                ListItemCollection listItems = tasksList.GetItems(camlQuery);

                ctx.Load(listItems, items => items.Include(
                    item => item.Id,
                    item => item.DisplayName,
                    item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
                    ));
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: Only the above version works. I get two listItems but I cannot read properties of the items. In DisplayName property I see "IC-Portal-Announcements"

Comment: Have you already tried to wrap your whole Query into <View>?
e.g _<View><Query>...</Query></View>_